# Why does GIT require sudo on my ntfs-3g partition?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, partition, fstab, ntfs-3g

When I try to init a new git repository on a ntfs-3g partition I get this error

```
% git init .
error: chmod on /mnt/abc/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

When I run the same command as `sudo git init .` it works.

As a normal user I can do `touch test.txt` and then edit and save that file.

This the output from cat `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=4ED0581F0CC0C861                           /mnt/abc       ntfs-3g         rw,user,exec,auto,umask=000     0 2
```

I also noticed that `make` and `cmake` also require sudo.

---

**Update 1**

Here is the output of `ls -l /mnt/abc/.git`:

```
total 2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Dec 25 16:46 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Dec 25 16:46 branches
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  93 Dec 25 16:46 config
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  73 Dec 25 16:46 description
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 528 Dec 25 16:46 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 144 Dec 25 16:46 info
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 240 Dec 25 16:46 objects
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 240 Dec 25 16:46 refs
```

Here the output of `ls -l /mnt/abc/.git/config.lock`

```
ls: cannot access '/mnt/rest/temp/.git/config.lock': No such file or directory
```

Here the output of `ls -l /mnt/abc/.git/config`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 93 Dec 25 16:46 /mnt/rest/temp/.git/config
```

**Update 2**

After following the link in the comment by @jsbillings I changed the fstab entry to (I removed umask=000)

```
UUID=5FC0580F0BC0C835                           /mnt/abc       ntfs-3g         rw,user,exec,auto       0 2
```

Then I `umount mnt/abc` and `mount mnt/abc`. Seems to have solved the problem. `git .init` and `cmake` run now.

Comment: show output of: `ls -l /mnt/abc/.git/ /mnt/abc/.git/config.lock`.

Comment: See this answer for a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/956395/git-init-shows-error-chmod-git-config-lock-failed-operation-not-permitte

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've updated my question.

Comment: You can easily diagnose permission problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`.